# AM modulation depth and phase addition

Tags: rf, power-electronics, electromagnetic, aviation-electronics

What does it mean when we say signal is 20% modulated or 40% modulated? Need detailed explanation. Also i want to know what happens when signal is overmodulated?

Comment: The accepted answer is also incorrect about overmodulation, and this is a product of using a nice simulation, and no understanding. gbarry gave a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If carrier (RF) signal is 10V, when the audio modulation is 0V, then 20% modulation means 12V (RF) on +ve modulation peaks and 8V (RF) on negative (audio) modulation peaks.

Overmodulation ,means that on negative modulation peaks the carrier goes hits 0